# Mathjax error in Rmarkdown+Shiny, even if Mathjax is set to 'null'

Tags: r, shiny, mathjax, r-markdown

I cannot manage to compile my .Rmd file within RStudio 0.98.1049, while it used to work before (a few weeks ago I guess).

Here is an example:

```
---
title: 'Test'
runtime: shiny
output: html_document 
---

# Context

Test
```

I get the following message, even if I add the option `mathjax: null` to the previous code:

```
Error in pandoc_mathjax_local_path() : 
  For mathjax = "local", please set the RMARKDOWN_MATHJAX_PATH 
environment variable to the location of MathJax. 
On Linux systems you can also install MathJax using your system package manager.
```

It works perfectly if I remove the mention `runtime: shiny`, but I want to keep it to get an interactive HTML document. 
Do you see where it comes from and/or what I should do? 
Thank you very much.

---

Here is my sessionInfo():

```
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252    LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=French_France.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.4    htmltools_0.2.6 rmarkdown_0.3.3 tools_3.1.1     yaml_2.1.13
```

Comment: Is anyone able to reproduce my (still ongoing) problem? Thank you.

Comment: I have followed the advice given [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/619): I run RStudio 0.98.1079, and now it works again.

Answer (score 0):

The newest versions of the rmarkdown package don't bundle MathJax anymore, as that made the package too large to be allowed on CRAN.

However, if you install the most recent RStudio (minimum version: 0.98.1058), it includes MathJax and will advertise to rmarkdown where it can go find it, so that should fix this issue.